# Как сохранить введенный текст в input после нажатия на кнопку button в файл?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Как сохранить введенный текст в input после нажатия на кнопку button в файл?**

```
<input id="write" type="text">
<button id="enter-input"></button>
```

Нужно сохранить все что в поле  в файл text.txt после нажатия на кнопку:  так, чтобы последующие сохранения текста, оказывались на 1 строчку нижу (списком)

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```html
<form action="main.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="myfile">
    <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Обработчик PHP

```php
//Принимаем данные
$myfile =  $_POST['myfile'];

//Формируем данные для записи в файл
$data =    . $_POST['myfile'] .  "\n";

// Записываем данные в файл
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'a');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо! Но когда нажимается кнопка отправки, страничка перехагружается/переходит на страничку скрипта самого, возможно ли это исправить как то..? (сделать незаметным, чтобы это происходило "фоново" не мешало уже загруженной страничке?) Спасибо Вам еще раз! =)

Comment: @ArSaakyan 
Вот тут почитайте https://fructcode.com/ru/blog/how-to-send-html-form-with-ajax/